# Wishing HR/recruiter of the future company happy new year

Tags: professionalism, communication

I am thinking to drop an email to my **future colleague** who was the first person I got to know from that company, and I know that company through her a short happy new year email. She is from the HR department and does the recruiting.

I am just thinking if this would be too much or unprofessional in any ways as I have never done it before?

Comment: `and I know that company through her a short happy new year email` what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is the, she is the one who approach me for the opportunity, and therefore she is the first person from the company that I got to know.

Answer (score 3):

A friendly email is perfectly okay. The same expectations of professionalism still apply though, so best to be brief.

You might also consider, in addition to a happy new year wish, to share that you've enjoyed getting to know your future colleague.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead. Send the wishes.

Don't *expect* a response though (mainly because, some may not even choose to open and respond to any email from a non-business domain).